# mapping values are not allowed here ... in foo.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this GAE python code

In file foo.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

         def get(self):
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
                self.response.write('Hello Foo')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug = True)
```

---

in file app.yaml

```
application: foo
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: foo.app
```

---

I get this error pointing to the third line in file foo.py ( class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler): )
Obs. Begin reading from the end of the message

```
...
line 172, in _HandleEvents
    for event in events:
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 212, in _GenerateEventParameters
    raise yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError(e)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "foo.py", line 3, column 39
```

---

I would appreciate a good help

thanks
Sam

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be doing so, but I think it's trying to read your Python script as a YAML file.

Answer (score 16):

This kind of error occurs if you start the application the wrong way: `dev_appserver.py foo.py`. You need a directory, e.g., `foo` with `foo/foo.py` and `foo/app.yaml` and then start the program from the parent directory with `dev_appserver.py foo/` or in the directory itself with `dev_appserver.py .`

Comment: This was my exact issue as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  I copy and pasted both into files and ran them on my Win7 system using App Engine SDK release: "1.7.7" and it served up the page without errors.

You may have issues with the files or your setup.

Have you tried the File->Creating New Application menu option? It will create a new application called engineapp that will display "Hello world!" when browsed on the localhost machine.